# How to change from a decimal to a binary in python

Tags: python, binary, decimal

So yeah I'm trying to figure a way on how to change a decimal into a binary in python

Comment: So you want to print an integer in binary?

Answer (score 3):

How about [`bin`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin):

```
>>> bin(42)
'0b101010'
```

Comment: This wont work. Try `bin(Decimal(10.9))` in python 2.x

Comment: @karthikr Indeed, `bin` is only for integers, as stated in the documentation. However, I don't think the OP referred to `decimal.Decimal`

Comment: there is no way to know that. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: def dec2bin(n):
   ...:     if not n:
   ...:         return ''
   ...:     else:
   ...:         return dec2bin(n/2) + str(n%2)
   ...:     

In [2]: dec2bin(11)
Out[2]: '1011'
```

Comment: Looks rather convoluted given that there are already standard functions to do just that.

Comment: @arshajii: Yeah, but I figured I'd give a DIY answer for completeness, just in case that's what OP was after